# My iPod touch won't let me save the new iTunes security questions

Tags: applications, ipod

Whenever I try to buy new apps, my iPod asks me to type in my user name and password and answer some security questions.

I tap OK to continue, but nothing happens. I have tried using a different account and even resetting my iPod but nothing seems to be working.

What can I do to fix this?

Even if I went on the compiter and enter my security questions it wouldn't let me save them. What will I do?

Comment: Which generation and operating system? I suspect older operating systems may not function correctly with it since it is new.

Comment: This might also help some people - http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/97422/how-do-i-reset-change-my-security-questions-on-my-ipod-touch

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest trying to download an app with iTunes on your computer. You may have better luck getting the questions there, and it shouldn't bug you about it on your iPod after you've done it.

Answer (score 1):

Are you under 13 ? Apple now block children from using iTunes - change your birthday to get round it (worked for my daughter).