# How do I reset/change my security questions on my iPod Touch?

Tags: itunes, ipod-touch, security, apple-id

On my iPod Touch, my mom changed the password to Apple/iTunes and I have a new iTunes gift card but I have to answer security questions and my mom and I both don't know them. How can I do this?

Comment: You might have to go through [iTunes support](https://expresslane.apple.com/Issues.action) if this article doesn't help… http://support.apple.com/kb/HT5312

Answer (score 2):

Apple's support article explains how to use a rescue email to reset the questions should you enter them and then forget them.

- http://support.apple.com/kb/HT5312

It has a link at the bottom where you can contact Apple's support if you can't get them reset yourself.